# I am having issues installing libraries to miniconda through the terminal

Tags: macos, tensorflow, command-line, miniconda

I am attempting to install Tensorflow on Miniconda with the intention of setting up Keras. Tensorflow is now setup, but I can't install the necessary libraries. For additional context this is on a mac. The current root I'm in is

```
/Users/myname/miniconda3
```

and I have my virtual environment running for Tensorflow.

I am attemting to execute the command

```
conda env update --file tools.yml
```

Which traces back to a file called tool.yml which I placed in the miniconda3 directory. When this command is ran I reccieve:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done                                                            
Solving environment: failed                                                                                  
                                                                                                             
ResolvePackageNotFound:                                                                                      
  - cudatoolkit=11.2.2                                                                                       
  - cudnn=8.1.0
```

The contents of the file are:

```
channels:
    - conda-forge
dependencies:
    - cudatoolkit=11.2.2 
    - cudnn=8.1.0
    - jupyter
    - scikit-learn
    - scipy
    - pandas
    - pandas-datareader
    - matplotlib
    - pillow
    - tqdm
    - requests
    - h5py
    - pyyaml
    - flask
    - boto3
    - pip
    - pip:
        - tensorflow
        - bayesian-optimization
        - gym
        - kaggle
```

I am new to miniconda and tensorflow, so I'm not sure if I am executing something incorrectly, if my tools.yml needs to be placed somewhere else, or if there is another issue. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using TensorFlow on your Mac, you may refer to any one of these 2 options I suggest :

## 1. Through Miniconda

Follow the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) for complete info.

a. Install the latest Python version. (Note: Requires Python 3.8–3.11, and pip >= 20.3 for MacOS.)

b. Install Miniconda

c. Create the conda environment.

d. Install TensorFlow

## 2. Through Miniforge (Check step no. 8 for GPU)

Follow these minimum steps for installing with Miniforge . You can get all the step by step details in this GitHub [Repo](https://github.com/mrdbourke/m1-machine-learning-test#how-to-setup-a-tensorflow-environment-on-m1-m1-pro-m1-max-using-miniforge-shorter-version)

1. Download and install Homebrew from https://brew.sh. Follow the steps it prompts you to go through after installation.
2. [Download Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh) (Conda installer) for macOS arm64 chips (M1, M1 Pro, M1 Max).
3. Install Miniforge3 into home directory.
4. Restart terminal.
5. Create a directory to setup TensorFlow environment.
6. Make and activate Conda environment.
7. Install TensorFlow dependencies from Apple Conda channel.
8. Install base TensorFlow (Apple's fork of TensorFlow is called tensorflow-macos)

The Github link provided above should be really helpful for getting all the commands for the steps. Additionally, you can check this [YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1CaUOHhI6U) video as well.